# Entity Framework 4.1 adds a GUID to entity object returned from DB

Tags: entity-framework, entity, guid, dbcontext

I have a strange problem when using Entity Framework code first.

When I return an object with `dbContext.Users.Where...` I don't get the `User` defined in my model, but `User_{GUID}`.

Is there anyone who knows this phenomenon and can help?

Regards,
Ajit

Comment: Read about [EF's concept of dynamic proxies](http://www.develop.com/entityframework4) - it does this to be able to track changes. [You can turn it off, if you want to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111109/should-i-enable-or-disable-dynamic-proxies-with-entity-framework-4-1-and-mvc3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `dbContext.Users` if of a type `DbSet<User>` then you would get a `User`-castable type instance if you query `Users` collection.

`User_{GUID}` looks like a dynamic proxy object to a `User` instance in your `DbContext`. Treat it as if it was a `User` instance.