# Web API Error: The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am getting this error when attempting to use a Web API controller.

> Web API Error: The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type

the code in my controller is as follows

```
public IEnumerable<Student> GetAllStudents()
    {
        var allstudents = unitOfWork.StudentRepository.Get(includeProperties: "Groups");


        return allstudents;
    }

    public Student GetStudentByID(Guid id)
    {
        return unitOfWork.StudentRepository.GetByID(id);
    }
```

and my 'Student' class is as follows

```
public partial class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        this.Groups = new HashSet<Group>();
    }

    public System.Guid StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Both methods result in the same error.

My inner exception is as follows

> Type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Student_4C97D068E1AD0BA62C3C6E441601FFB7418AD2D635F7F1C14B64F4B2BE32DF9A'
>   with data contract name
>   'Student_4C97D068E1AD0BA62C3C6E441601FFB7418AD2D635F7F1C14B64F4B2BE32DF9A:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any
>   types  not known statically to the list of known types - for example,
>   by using the  KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the
>   list of known types  passed to DataContractSerializer.

I have a feeling I need to use the `KnownType` attribute but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the inner exception message?  The inner exception message will be the actual exception that is thrown by the serializer and it should tell us which type is causing the exception.

Let me guess -- Is it any the type `Course` and the type `Group`?  If so, try putting `KnownType` attribute on the actual implementation type of your `class Student`

```
[KnownType(typeof(GroupA))]
[KnownType(typeof(CourseA))]
public partial class Student
{...}

public class GroupA : Group {...}
public class CourseA : Course {...}

public interface Group {...}
public interface Course {...}
```

Comment: Hi Maggie, thanks for the reply.  I've added the inner exception above.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. @jjc99 -- why did you mark this as answered? The problem lies in that the type that inherits from Student is created at runtime by the Entity Framework as a dynamic proxy object, thus it's impossible to use the compile-time KnownType attribute for it.

Comment: @Paul, you may be right. What I know is that the `KnownTypeAttribute` has the `Inherited=true` option set. This means if the actual implementation of `GroupA` or `Student` inherits respectively from `GroupA` and `Student` (thus a cast is possible), and the serializer uses `Type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KnownTypeAttribute), true)` internally, this will work. Still, I am not familiar with these internal details to absolutely support my words, I just think it is possible even if the concrete types are dynamically generated.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need the lazy-loaded navigation properties provided by the proxy class (`System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Student_4C97D068E1A...`), you can disable their generation by setting:

```
unitOfWork.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

What to do if you need the proxy class is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13959048/145173).

---

Follow these links for a good overview of lazy loading and proxies:

- [Loading Related Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)
- [Working with Proxies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx)
- [Should I enable or disable dynamic proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7111109/145173)

I usually disable lazy loading and proxies by default, and enable one or both in specific code blocks that need them.

Comment: If he still need the navigation properties they can be included with
`return allStudents.Include( i => i.Groups)`