# The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

Tags: c#, json.net

For months the following web API 2 (simplified example) responded correctly to

```
http://localhost/TestApi2/api/tests with this. 
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Naples"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Paris"}] 
    //using Newtonsoft.Json;
    namespace TestApi2.Controllers
    {
        public class PersonsController : ApiController
        {
            [HttpGet]
            [Route("api/tests")]
            public HttpResponseMessage GetAll()
            {
                //  This is a dbContext generated from a DatabaseFirst EF Generation
                using (var cleanDbContext = new cleanDbEntities())
                {
                    var tests = cleanDbContext.TestTables;
                    // Return all
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, tests, Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I updated my NuGets on the Project
The same call responded with:

```
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
```

Apparently something in the NuGet update, perhaps Newtonsoft, the Formatter, cannot Serialize the list implied in the "var list =". The list is ok because I can foreach through it to examine the contents.

After a lot of agony, and experimentation, I changed the query to explicitly generate a list while keeping the anonymous var target.

```
var tests = cleanDbContext.TestTables.ToList();
```

Modifying the query to explicitly generate a List fixed the issue. I'll send this info to Newtonsoft. It's a great product.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't updated EF packages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp.Net Web API Error: The 'ObjectContent\`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959048/asp-net-web-api-error-the-objectcontent1-type-failed-to-serialize-the-respon)