# Getting an error on request

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to Web API. I just want to return some List on some method call, in which its verb is HttpGet.

Upon giving the request in the browser, I have received the following error:

> Web API Error: The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'

I have searched for the solution, and finally,

```
DBContextObjName.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

is the one, which solves the error.

But I just want to know, how this solves the error. I mean in which way the solution and the error related.

May I kindly know, the explanation for it. So I can understand this, more clearly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MSDN [DbContextConfiguration.ProxyCreationEnabled Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.proxycreationenabled%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether or not the framework will
>   create instances of **dynamically generated proxy classes** whenever it
>   creates an instance of an entity type. Note that even if proxy
>   creation is enabled with this flag, proxy instances will only be
>   created for entity types that meet the requirements for being proxied.
>   Proxy creation is enabled by default.

Knowing that if you look at a few others who had similar issue

[Failed to serialize the response in Web API with Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23098326/5233410)

[failed to serialize the response in Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20252040/5233410)

[Asp.Net Web API Error: The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23372600/5233410)

The dynamically generated proxy classes cannot be serialized has issues when formatters try to serialize it.

Some cases mentioned circular references associated navigation properties.