# Many to Many Query with Generic Repostitory

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, many-to-many

Could someone please point me in the right direction of querying a many to many relationship. I'm trying to get a List of all active Machine Operators and for the life of me cannot seem to get it right.

***If its of any use, this is what I've been trying up to now***

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        using (DAL.Repositories.Repository<Machine> machineRepo = new DAL.Repositories.Repository<Machine>())
        using (DAL.Repositories.Repository<Operator> operatorRepo = new DAL.Repositories.Repository<Operator>())
        {
            List<int> OperatorIDs = new List<int>();
            List<Machine> Machine = new List<Machine>();

            OperatorIDs = operatorRepo.FindAll(x => x.Active).Select(y => y.ID).ToList();

            var machineOperators = machineRepo.FindAll(x => x.Active).Select(x => x.Operators.All(o => OperatorIDs.Contains(o.ID)));


            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, machineOperators);
        }
    }
```

**My code as follows**

```
public class Operator
{
    public Operator()
    {
        Machines = new HashSet<Machine>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    // Navigational Link
    public virtual ICollection<Machine> Machines { get; set; }
}

public class Machine
{
    public Machine()
    {
        Departments = new HashSet<Department>();
        Operators = new HashSet<Operator>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Operator> Operators { get; set; }
}
```

**And in my efContext**

```
public MachineConfiguration()
    {
        // Key
        HasKey(x => x.ID);

        // Fields
        Property(x => x.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        Property(x => x.MachineName).IsRequired();

        // Table
        ToTable("Machine");

        // Relationships
        HasMany(e => e.Operators)
            .WithMany(e => e.Machines)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("MachineOperators")
                .MapLeftKey("MachineID")
                .MapRightKey("OperatorID"));
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to return? All the active machines that have all the operators in active?

Comment: A list of Active Machines with their corresponding Active Operators

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    using (DAL.Repositories.Repository<Machine> machineRepo = new DAL.Repositories.Repository<Machine>())
    {
        var machineOperators = machineRepo.FindAll(x => x.Active).Include(x=>x.Operators).Where(x => x.Operators.All(o =>o.Active)).ToList();

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, machineOperators);
    }
}
```

Comment: Returns the active machines, but no operators
`{
        "$id": "1",
        "ID": 1,
        "MachineName": "Roland X1000",
        "Active": true,
        "Operators": [],
        "Departments": []
    }`

Comment: Maybe you have disabled lazy loading, try eager loading that nav property using the `Include` extension method.

Comment: Now I saw your `Operator` nav property is not `virtual`, If you want that EF tracks the changes in your entities and lazy load your navigation properties, you need to declare them as virtual: `public virtual ICollection<Operator> Operators { get; set; }`

Comment: Yes, that worked great. Now i'm faced with this error when the results are returned.
`The 'ObjectContent1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: Check the answers in these posts: [post1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a5adf07b-e622-4a12-872d-40c753417645/web-api-error-the-objectcontent1-type-failed-to-serialize-the-response-body-for-content), [post2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959048/asp-net-web-api-error-the-objectcontent1-type-failed-to-serialize-the-respon) and [post3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936713/web-api-error-the-objectcontent1-type-failed-to-serialize-the-response-body)

Comment: Lazy loading and serialization are not "_good friends_".  Probably you may need to disable [proxy creation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx) but first try the solution that is recomended in the [post1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a5adf07b-e622-4a12-872d-40c753417645/web-api-error-the-objectcontent1-type-failed-to-serialize-the-response-body-for-content)

Comment: It would seem that code is already in place, disabling the ProxyCreation works but it creates a weird output in JSON but this also breaks other areas of my application.

Comment: well my friend, those are the solutions that you will find to resolve that problem. ;).  I think you should create a new question to see if some user who have previously had  the same issue can help you.