# Entity Framework - Code First mapping issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it possible to have a foreign key mapping based on a specific column value.

I have the following entities.

```
public class Controller
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ControllerDevice> ActiveDevices { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ControllerDevice> TamperedDevices { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ControllerDevice> IgnoredDevices { get; set; }
}

public class ControllerDevice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DeviceStatus Status { get; set; }

    public int ControllerId { get; set; }
    public int NetworkDeviceId { get; set; }

    public virtual Controller Controller { get; set; }
    public virtual NetowkDevice NetowkDevice { get; set; }
}

public class NetowkDevice
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public enum DeviceStatus
{
    Active,
    Tampered,
    Ignored
}
```

Is it possible to have the `ActiveDevices`, `TamperedDevices` and `IngoredDevices` list be auto populated based on `ControllerDevice` `DeviceStatus`, or would I have to create three different tables for each list. IE `ActiveControllerDevice`, `TamperedControllerDevices` and `IgnoredControllerDevices`.

Please let me know if you require further explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single devices collection:

```
public class Controller
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ControllerDevice> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

...and filter it, when you need to process or display devices with specific `Status` value:

```
controller.Devices.Where(d => d.Status == DeviceStatus.Active);
```

Several tables for each devices status, and/or devices hierarchy (theoretically, you can solve this problem with a TPH inheritance) is a way to hell, because instead of single entity `ControllerDevice` with a status you'll get three entity types (`ActiveControllerDevice`, `TamperedControllerDevice` and `IgnoredControllerDevice`), which is not corresponding to model.

Instead of changing status, the device will change its *type*, and you cannot do that in simple way.

Comment: Hi Dennis, I think I was trying to over complicate things, this looks like a much better solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Enum support was introduced in Entity Framework 5, .Net Framework 4.5. In Entity Framework, an enumeration can have the following underlying types:  Byte, Int16,  Int32,  Int64 , or SByte.

And you can filter like this:

```
context.ControllerDevices.Where(d => d.Status == DeviceStatus.Active);
```

More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx

Comment: OP asking about ability to filter data when *mapping*, not *querying*.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
   public TestContext()
   {
      Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
      Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
      Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
      Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
   }

   public virtual DbSet<NetowkDevice> NetowkDevices{ get; set; }
   public virtual DbSet<ControllerDevice> ControllerDevices{ get; set; }
   public virtual DbSet<Controller> Controlleres{ get; set; }
}
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/d0443029-2175-4bde-a834-4f8dbf313201/

[Should I enable or disable dynamic proxies with entity framework 4.1 and MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111109/should-i-enable-or-disable-dynamic-proxies-with-entity-framework-4-1-and-mvc3)

Comment: How this answers original question?