# Why would an EF query with ToListAsync hang in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, prism

This is the query:

```
using (var db = new AppDbContext())
{
    var items = await db.Branches
        .Where(b => b.OrgId == orgId)
        .Select(t => new SelectListItem<int> {Key = t.Id, Value = t.Name})
        .ToListAsync();
    return items;
}
```

If I replace `ToListAsync` with `ToList`, it runs fine, but otherwise it hangs. I suspect some sort of threading issue. The query is called during my viewmodel's `InitializeAsync` method, which is called from an 'event' in the view:

```
public override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
    await InitializeModelAsync(InitModelCts.Token);
}
```

This is part of the view's implementation of `INavigationAware`.

Comment: This might help: [ToListAsync() does not complete at all](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25899982/6741868)

Comment: Check for ThreadId in both the cases .If they are different then use dispatcher instead

Comment: Could this be because `OnNavigatedTo` isn't really `async` from the beginning? I found [this blog](https://invokeit.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/async-await-and-onnavigatedto-wpdev-win8dev/).

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you don't capture the context by calling the `ConfigureAwait` method?:

```
using (var db = new AppDbContext())
{
    var items = await db.Branches
        .Where(b => b.OrgId == orgId)
        .Select(t => new SelectListItem<int> { Key = t.Id, Value = t.Name })
        .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return items;
}
```

Also note the initial Entity Framework setup is not really asynchronous:

[EF6 ToListAsync freezes Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578759/ef6-tolistasync-freezes-winforms/27582525)

...so you might want to offload the entire query and context creation to a background thread:

```
await Task.Run(()=> 
{
    using (var db = new AppDbContext())
    {
        var items = db.Branches
                    .Where(b => b.OrgId == orgId)
                    .Select(t => new SelectListItem<int> { Key = t.Id, Value = t.Name })
                    .ToList();
        return items;
    }
});
```

Comment: I solved it using `SynchronizationContext.Post`, with a delegate that awaits the query, as is with `ToListAsync`.